# Root element is missing when load XmlDocument from a stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exception

I have the following code:

```
var XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(response.ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine();

// setup the XML namespace manager
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(XmlDoc.NameTable);
// add the relevant namespaces to the XML namespace manager
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://triblue.com/SeriousPayments/");
XmlDoc.LoadXml(response.ReadToEnd());
XmlElement NodePath = (XmlElement)XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Response", mgr);

while (NodePath != null)
  {
      foreach (XmlNode Xml_Node in NodePath)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(Xml_Node.Name + " " + Xml_Node.InnerText);
      }
  }
```

I am getting:

> Root element is missing.

at:

```
XmlDoc.LoadXml(response.ReadToEnd());
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://triblue.com/SeriousPayments/">
    <Result>0</Result>
    <Message>Pending</Message>
    <PNRef>230828</PNRef>
    <ExtData>InvNum=786</ExtData>
</Response>
```

I'm lost. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I know I had this working before so I'm not sure what I screwed up.

As always, thanks!

* Reason for my edit after I got my answer ****

I needed to change the line:

```
XmlElement NodePath = (XmlElement)XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Response");
```

to:

```
XmlElement NodePath = (XmlElement)XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Response", mgr);
```

This will not work without it.

Comment: What does Console.WriteLine(response.ReadToEnd()); output?

Comment: How do you expect anything "substantial" to come from **steam** ?? :-) (sorry, couldn't resist...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you're reading the `response` stream twice. It doesn't work that way, you get an empty string the second time. Either remove the line `Console.WriteLine(response.ReadToEnd());` or save the response to a string:

```
string responseString = response.ReadToEnd();
…
Console.WriteLine(reponseString);
…
XmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
```

Comment: 24 seconds faster than me, I think I have to improve my typing speed :)

Comment: Great! TY! That got me past that line! I'm getting this now at the nodepath line: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: @ErocM, comments are not good for asking or answering questions. You should ask a completely new question.

Comment: Nice! This helped me correct my approach with a .NET Core API and an `HTTPRequest` (`Request.Body`) via an instance of the `StreamReader` class, within a `using` statement. This also led me to realize I was using the `Load()` method and should have been using the `LoadXml()` method. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should store the XML readers input in a string variable, since the second time the `ReadToEnd()` method is being called, it can not read anything from the stream, as it is already at the end and returns an empty string.

```
string responseString = response.ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

when you call
Console.WriteLine(response.ReadToEnd());
it reads all responde content at second time you can read it agiin

```
string responsecontent=response.ReadToEnd();
```

and use responsecontent anywhere

Answer (score 0):

while deserializing use deserializeRootElementName as "root"

**XmlDocument xmlResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(response,"root");**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Can you add an explanation on how your code solves the problem? You can find information about code formatting in this [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).